# Result of dao.createOrUpdate() in ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

I wonder if it is possible to find out if ORMLite's `dao.createOrUpdate()` method has actually created or updated a table row. There is a result Object (`CreateOrUpdateStatus`), which contains these informations, but all indicating fields (`created`, `updated` and `numLinesChanged`) are package-visible only. Is that a bug or does anyone have an idea why is that so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Oh what an epic fail.  This is definitely a bug which was fixed in version 4.25 on 8/22/2011.  Sorry about this @steffen.

The permissions on that class have been corrected:

```
public class CreateOrUpdateStatus {
    ...
    public boolean isCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public boolean isUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }
    public int getNumLinesChanged() {
        return numLinesChanged;
    }
}
```